# Unzip returns "Unsupported compression method 14"

Tags: linux, macos, command-line

I recently downloaded a large number of GIS data files from a government agency to a file server and need to unzip all of them via the command line. However, `unzip filename.zip` is returning "Unsupported compression method 14". What does this mean? How can I extract the files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These files were compressed using the LZMA algorithm (possibly using WinZip). LZMA archives are not supported by the `unzip` command. I found that I could extract these files using 7z instead, as follows:

1. Install [p7zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/) (from source or package manager)
2. `7z x filename.zip`

Comment: WinZip specific compression method codes are [available here](http://www.winzip.com/wz54.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If You still receive unsupported format warning, You can install [p7zip-full](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) package.

p7zip-full provides 7z and 7za which support more compression formats.
For example for extracting the file zipfile.zip

1. sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
2. 7za e zipfile.zip